# How would I do about filling in this hole?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, path, transparency

[image: Image here]

I want to fill in that little space in the bottom right-hand corner, but every time I use something like the pen or paint it creates it in a new layer, which when using the stroke feature, completely messes it up. How do I fill this gap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> or go to `View → Outline` via the main menu
- Hit <kbd>A</kbd> or choose the `Direct Selection Tool` from the toolbar
- Select only those anchor points that belong to that "white" shape
- Hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

1. Make a Path to fill that little space.
2. Pick the color and apply using the Eyedropper tool
3. Expand them both
4. Finally, create a Compound Shape to merge them both.
5. Make a Path to fill that little space.

[image]

2. Pick the color and apply using the Eyedropper tool.

[image]

3. Expand them both.

[image]

4. Finally, create a Compound Shape to merge them both.

[image]

Final Image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the icon and use the shape builder or paint bucket tool to fill it.
You can also use the delete anchor point tool to delete the anchor points that belongs to the shape.